# Copy images from Assets to Cache (ImageLoader)

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I need make copy from assets to cache pictures.

I have got MD5 file name in assets (image http url).

I made copy as here:

```
DiskCache diskCache = ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache();
        File fileDirectory = diskCache.getDirectory();
        copyAssets(context, fileDirectory);
```

I try read file with UniveralImageLoader as:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(castle.getImageUrl(), this.castleImage, imageOptions);
```

but image isn't read.

Any sugestions?

**SOLUTION**

```
cache.save(uri, in, copylistener)
```

Comment: image loader uses its own file naming scheme to identify and serve requests from cache. Try to observe that naming scheme and save the images with those file names. Although,i dont understand why you need a disk cache when you are loading the images from disk anyway? You usually use a disk cache to avoid something costlier (like a web request)

Comment: @VinayWadhwa in case of images you may need to use the cache to store scalled down version of your image, so next time you are going to show it, there will be less data to decode, this you might show them faster, depending on how big the original image is and what target resolution/density etc device is using

Comment: I see.. Why don't you let the ImageLoader handle it? Load your image with a URI like "file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png" from the sd card or from the assets itself like "assets://image.png"

Comment: I need make a trick. My objects (from database) have got pictures with url.
With my initial database I need some of them work in offline mode until path of image (in object) are changed. I think about naming images the same as image loader when cache from target url, paste in assets and on first init copy to image loader cache. Image loader should check picture is exist in cache and load this.